# iwlist --> Interface doesn't support scanning

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

First of all, excuse me if my english is bad, I'm french.
I switched my computer on Debian 10 Buster but I can't use Wifi. In fact, I can't scan for wifi because my interfaces don't support scanning.
If I use `sudo` for almost every command it's just because I still didn't add myself to the sudoers file.
Before posting this topic, I searched on other topics about that issue but I didn't find anything helpful for me.

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for kowalski: 
enp60s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3e2c:30ff:fead:f5c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:2c:30:ad:f5:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37935  bytes 27738109 (26.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9545  bytes 1682099 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 196  bytes 15300 (14.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196  bytes 15300 (14.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.186.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.186.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.233.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.233.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is the result of ifconfig, the 2 last interfaces are used by a Virtual Machine.

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5004 (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

This is the result of lspci

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

enp60s0   no wireless extensions.
```

This is the result of iwconfig

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo iwlist enp60s0 scan
enp60s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

And finally, this is what I get when I try to scan my main interface.

Please, can someone help me ? I have to notice that the wired connection works.

Thanks a lot.

## UPDATE

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wifi
[   20.270300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.279464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode (-2)
[   20.279508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode failed with error -2
```

This error appears several times, and the end of the output is :

```
[   20.279889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-30
[   20.279925] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38
[   20.279958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: None of the listed interfaces are wireless ones. `en`something means wired Ethernet, which is why it can't scan for anything. For some reason the Intel wireless interface isn't available. It's either that the driver (`iwlwifi`) isn't installed or couldn't start, typically because you don't have the necessary firmware installed. Please check your kernel log (`journalctl -k` or `dmesg`) and add anything relevant to the question.

Comment: `enp60s0` is not a wireless interface. when you do the `iwconfig` it should show something like `interface    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:".....`  instead of `enp60s0   no wireless extensions`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that it was only a wired interface. I'll post the output of `dmesg` and `journalctl -k` in my post in one or two min.
@binarysta, I know that, I saw it on many other topics, but I don't have this, and I don't know why.

Comment: Ok I found how to do it, thanks to you two. I'm gonna explain it in an answer to my question, I don't know if it's how we close a topic.

Comment: Hi Kowalski, and welcome to Unix & Linux! Answers are indicated here by clicking on the checkmark (which should show up at some point for your self-answer), not by having certain words in the titles. Thanks for your contribution to the site!

Comment: I just [tracked it down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) -- you have to wait two days to accept a self-answer.  While I'm here, I'll encourage you to go through our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), to get more familiar with how the site works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a solution.

I had to install firmware-iwlwifi, so I added "non-free" after the sources I use, in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then, I did :

```
sudo apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Then, after running `sudo iwlist`, I finally had :

```
kowalski@debian:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"******"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: **:**:**:**:**:**   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:9   Missed beacon:0

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

enp60s0   no wireless extensions.
```

where I just hid what was "personal"
and my Wifi was able to connect via Network Manager.